Postgres - Query distinct/longest date ranges
I'm looking to apply some logic that returns the distinct/longest date ranges in a particular table. In the example below, PKID 1 contains the date ranges in 2-4, then is proceeded by 5. I can't think of a good way to return 1 and 5 without writing multiple MIN() and MAX() aggregates, comparing lengths of time, or writing a 10 line CASE statement with LAG() functions. Is there an easier way to return PKID 1 and 5 without doing 20 levels of logic tests?
I've found a few posts that come close to this problem but aren't the same. I can't think of a way to implement the OVERLAP function in this instance, but enjoyed learning about it.
Find overlapping date ranges in PostgreSQL
How to find overlapping date ranges in Postgresql between multiple rows?
Postgresql query between date ranges


Do you mean this?
WITH
indata(pkid,start_dt,end_dt) AS (
            SELECT 1,DATE '2020-06-29',DATE '2023-04-30'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,DATE '2020-06-29',DATE '2021-06-27'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3,DATE '2022-03-07',DATE '2022-03-07'
  UNION ALL SELECT 4,DATE '2022-03-14',DATE '2022-03-14'
  UNION ALL SELECT 5,DATE '2023-05-01',DATE '2025-08-06'
)
SELECT
  *
FROM indata
ORDER BY end_dt - start_dt LIMIT 2
;




pkid
start_dt
end_dt




1
2020-06-29
2023-04-30


5
2023-05-01
2025-08-06



Or this?
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE 
indata(pkid,start_dt,end_dt)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS  AS (
            SELECT 1,DATE '2020-06-29',DATE '2023-04-30'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,DATE '2020-06-29',DATE '2021-06-27'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3,DATE '2022-03-07',DATE '2022-03-07'
  UNION ALL SELECT 4,DATE '2022-03-14',DATE '2022-03-14'
  UNION ALL SELECT 5,DATE '2023-05-01',DATE '2025-08-06'
);

WITH RECURSIVE rec_query(pkid,start_dt,end_dt) AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM indata
  WHERE pkid = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    next.*
  FROM indata AS next
  JOIN rec_query AS prev
    ON prev.end_dt + 1 = next.start_dt
)
SELECT * FROM rec_query;




pkid
start_dt
end_dt




1
2020-06-29
2023-04-30


5
2023-05-01
2025-08-06




Your 2nd answer seems to do the trick. I'm testing out the results now. One question I had is, because I'm not terribly familiar with the RECURSIVE CTE: I was able to replicate the results of the RECURSIVE function by just referencing indata again. Any reason why I shouldn't do that?

So, instead of JOIN rec_query AS prev, I just referenced indata for rec_query as well as removing the top WITH RECURSIVE line and it produced the same result.

Nevermind my question! I found an instance using the method I mentioned and the comparison was done without anchoring to the top half of the UNION. RECURSIVE maintains the comparison.
